# 4 to 1 multiplexer using BC549 transistor

Tags: transistors, multiplexer

I would like to know how to make a 4 to 1 multiplexer using BC549 transistors also the it has a function wherein I can select which input or output to send HIGH or LOW just like the 4051 multiplexer.

Comment: It'd help a bit if you explained why you need to do this, and why the 4051 isn't suitable.

Comment: Afaik the 4051 datasheet has an equivalent circuit schematic

Comment: You won't be able to make a decent analog multiplexer using BJT transistors: there is a good reason such muxes are made using CMOS technology.

Comment: I need to do this because their is no 4051 at my local electronic shop and I need to pass this 4 to 1 multiplexer early morning the following day so I kinda researched what possible alternatives I can do then the idea of using BC549 appeared but it is not clear, so can you please help me

Comment: Forget it. Get a bunch of relays, that might just about be doable (and more understandable for you).

Comment: You still don't tell us the application you need the mux for. As @WoutervanOoijen already told you, BJTs is an awful choice to build an analog MUX. Tell us the specs of the application and we could give you better suggestions.

Comment: I would like to add more pins for my Arduino digital IO